# Can the default location for SSL certificates for Postgresql be changed?

Tags: postgresql, ssl

For maintaining the server and client certificates , the default location for Postgresql is `~/.postgresql/root.crl` (`%APPDATA%\postgresql\root.crl` on Microsoft Windows).

I have learned that the default location can be overridden overridden by the connection parameters `sslcert` and `sslkey` or the environment variables `PGSSLCERT` and `PGSSLKEY`.

Can anyone help me in how to do this and what are the steps involved?

Comment: You want instructions how to set an environment variable?

Comment: No, i want to understand using sslcert and sslkey, how can i override the default location? Where i need to set the path for this? i have made a simple JDBC client and using the URL and ssl as:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=testssl&ssl=true&sslmode=verify-full.

Comment: Oh, I see. You read the documentation for `libpq`, but you need the [JDBC driver documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html).